# How to assert that memory is freed

Tags: c++, c, memory-leaks, free, assert

I have a function in which there is a free of memory.

and I want after calling this function assert that the function has freed the given memory.

And I could not change any thing in this function.

I need that for uni tests. I want to test my function, I want to check that my function really free the memory after calling it

The question is in the code

```
void func(char *mem)
{
  // Some where in the function there is a free of the memory
  // The free could be into if condition so there is a risk to not be executed
}

int main()
{
   char *mem = malloc(20);
   func(mem);
   // how to assert here that the memory is freed?
}
```

Comment: You don't need to. If you `free()` memory, it will be freed.

Comment: @H2CO3 read the question closer.

Comment: @gbtimmon I did read the question fully. The design is flawed, and this is an XY problem. The solution is not "asserting if the memory was freed".

Comment: I am not sure, but perhaps what you are trying to ascertain is if the memory was really freed, if not assert or error out. This is probably already implemented inside free. You don't need to check for it. If you want to do, this will become messy and complex

Comment: @H2CO3 I agree with you.  We have to keep track ourselves.

Comment: The question is this. I have a function that may or may not free memory, depending on program state. I cannot edit the function, but I need  to check that the function DOES free memory under this certain conditions. How do you accomplish this? You can justify all you want, but short uncommited answers shows disrespect for the asker.

Comment: I need that for unit tests. I want to test my fucntion, I want to check that my function really free the memory after calling it

Comment: I have an idea, i'm not sure, but perhaps instead of code change, valgrind can provide this answer. I mean it will not error out, but it can provide a log which can assure if free was indeed called

Answer (score 5):

Short answer: There's no way to achieve that.

Usual way to ensure free'd memory is not re-used accidentally or identify some pointer is free'd is to set it to NULL immediately after freeing it. To achieve that, in your example, you need to make changes to `func()`. If you can't make any changes to `func()` then there's no way to ascertain whether the pointer passed to it is freed or still valid.

Besides if you func() is going to free memory for some calls and not for other calls then it's a bad design. There's got to be a better and transparent way to manage dynamically allocated memory.

Comment: I need that for uni tests. I want to test my fucntion andd I want to check that my function really free the memory. it's not related to my program design

Comment: In that case, you can make func() set the pointer to NULL when it *frees* and check for the NULL in your caller function.

Comment: How setting the pointer to NULL would help us in ascertaining that memory was freed? because the pointer in func() is a copy and we change that copy to NULL so there is no change in main's varible "mem".

Comment: @ASHISHNEGI You can pass the pointer to the pointer to modify the pointer in the caller or make the function return the null or some other unique value that let the caller know that the pointer passed in was free'd. If func() can be modified then it's a matter of taste on how you want to implement that.